# Notation $\ker S = \mathbb{R}\{a_j\}$ not clear to me

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, notation

has anyone ever seen the following notation:

$\ker S = \mathbb{R}\{a_j\}$,

where $a_j$ is the j-th column of some (arbitrary) Matrix and S is some covariance Matrix?

To give a little bit more context: I found this on some slides over optimization (linear chance constraints).

The left hand side is fine, but I don't know what is ment by the term $\mathbb{R}\{a_j\}$.
I'm very confused, because I have never seen such a Notation. Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: I would guess it means the space spanned by $a_j$.

Comment: thx for your comment. Yes, from the context it seems to be the real space spanned by $a_j$. That makes sense - but still quite unusual notation for that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a_j$ is a vector. So, of course, we know what does the $\lambda a_j$ mean for every $\lambda \in \mathbb R$.

So the standard notation $\mathbb R a_j$ for the set (actually, a space) $\{\lambda a_j$ $|$ $\lambda \in \mathbb R \}$ is quite logical, isn't it?